# Blackhole attack simulation in Network Simulator-2.35

Tags: ns2

I'm getting following error while implementing Blackhole attack in NS-allinone-2.35

```
ns: _o107 hacker: 
    (_o107 cmd line 1)
    invoked from within
"_o107 cmd hacker"
    invoked from within
"catch "$self cmd $args" ret"
    invoked from within
"if [catch "$self cmd $args" ret] {
set cls [$self info class]
global errorInfo
set savedInfo $errorInfo
error "error when calling class $cls: $args" $..."
    (procedure "_o107" line 2)
    (SplitObject unknown line 2)
    invoked from within
"_o107 hacker"
```

Here, Hacker is the blackhole node

I have checked my blackhole.tcl file, it is ok...

the problem is somewhere else....

Comment: did you add lines in .cc file for hacker args?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

splitObject error is a spacing error. I guess, you did a spacing error where you have mentioned "hacker". check it in both tcl file and aodv.cc file.